# Calling event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

In below code as you can see data get it values from dropdown menu text i need data to get it values from href and replace # with "" to get values without # sgin

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Default2.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'value':'" + $('#<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>').val() + "',$('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click();}", dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.d.length > 0) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split('/')[0],
                                    val: item.split('/')[1]
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                        else {
                            response([{ label: 'No Records Found', val: -1 }]);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            },
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span id="search_concept">Filter by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#UserID">User ID</a></li>
            <li><a href="#TypeName">User Type</a></li>
        </ul>


    </div>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi the code gets values stored in href which i need to use in this function instead of text                         data: "{'value':'" + $('#<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>').val() + "','filterBy':'" + $('#search_concept').text() + "'}", dataType: "json",

Comment: Please put that in your question. It helps to know your reasons to do this, and also the code you just pasted will be readable then.

Comment: @ShaunakD - There are many reasons why an event handler might need to be triggered.

Comment: i will update my question

Comment: @JaredFarrish I assumed it was about defining the handler, and not triggering it. I might be wrong, which is why I asked for clarification first.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.search-panel .dropdown-menu a').dispatchEvent('click');`

Answer (score 1):

Its an event handler that will be called on click, but you can call it like this:

```
$('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is helpful.Let us put all the function code outside the document ready and call the function whenever the body is loaded as per the event triggered.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
//calling the function
     function myEvents();
    });
   //now you can define  the function as per your requirement
   function myEvents(){
     $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
            var concept = $(this).text();
            $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
            return concept;
        });   
    };

</script>
```